# Differential of $Re(e^{x-iy})$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I want to calculate differential of $Re(e^{x-iy})$ in point $(0,-\pi)$. If $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, it's easy: $Re(e^{x-iy}) = Re(e^x(\cos y - i\sin y)) = e^x \cos y$, so  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}|_{(0,-\pi)} = -1, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}|_{(0,-\pi)} = 0$ and differential $= -h_{1}$. But what should i do in case $x,y \in \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by differential, but it can't have a derivative in the usual sense. The derivative is a 'best' linear approximation, and if the derivative is non zero, then locally the function behaves like $h \mapsto f(x)+f'(x)h$, so choosing appropriate $h$ would mean the function has complex values.

Comment: @copper.hat
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function#Differentials_in_several_variables
I mean this

Comment: That notation is a little shaky for me, but I think the same reasoning applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function
$$f(x,y):={\rm Re}\bigl(e^{x-iy}\bigr)$$
is not complex differentiable with respect to the variables $x$ and/or $y$. But we can put $x=x_1+ i x_2$, $y=y_1+i y_2$ and consider $f$ as a real-valued  function
of the four real variables $x_1$, $x_2$, $y_1$, and $y_2$:
$$\tilde f(x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2):=f(x_1+i x_2,y_1+i y_2)=e^{x_1+y_2}\cos(x_2-y_1)$$
(check this!). Computing
$$\tilde f_{.x_1}(x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2)=e^{x_1+y_2}\cos(x_2-y_1)$$
and similarly for the others one obtains
$$\tilde f_{.x_1}(0,0,-\pi,0)=\tilde f_{.y_2}(0,0,-\pi,0)=-1\ ,$$
$$\tilde f_{.x_2}(0,0,-\pi,0)=\tilde f_{.y_1}(0,0,-\pi,0)=0\ .$$
It follows that
$$d\tilde f(0,0,-\pi,0).(X_1,X_2,Y_1,Y_2)=-X_1-Y_2\ .$$
That's all I could make out of your question.